# Azure Logic App custom connector SOAP endpoint using WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, azure-logic-apps, power-automate-custom-connector

I am using a Logic App for which I need to create a custom connector. This connector depends on a web service, for which I am trying to add using wsdl definition.
[image: Add connector]

Now If I provide the url, it needs authentication, which I am not able to provide via this UI. I can see the parameters can be provided while using it in the logic app. However it fails to pull the services and hence not creating the definition for the connector

[image: Auth Credentials parameters]

I tried downloading the wsdl and adding here as a file, but the schema have xs import tags, because of which its failing again. And as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9161756), I can not replace it with actual schema.

```
<xs:import namespace="http://some.name/" schemaLocation="./path/to/it.xsd"/>
```

Is there a way that I do not need to provide the custom connector definition manually and make it work using wsdl, as it contains a lot of endpoints and it would be too much to add all actions and triggers manually. Plus it would be also reference for me if needed in future for such scenario

Answer (score 1):

You may try this if the services are accessible over the internet, then you call service endpoint over HTTP or HTTPS from azure logic apps. This article will help you with details steps to be followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http

If it is not accessible over the internet then this article will help with step by step process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection

Before you can access data sources on premises from your logic apps, you need to create an Azure resource after you install the on-premises data gateway on a local computer. Your logic apps then use this Azure gateway resource in the triggers and actions provided by the on-premises connectors that are available for Azure Logic Apps.

[image]

Also check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#how-the-gateway-works)

Comment: Hello Jaya, this is not I am looking for