# 2 classes with same methods and properties (ambiguous references) C#

Tags: c#, ambiguous

I have 2 XSD'd that I turned into classes. Company and Person class. The XSD's have several included tags that referenced the same data. Example:

```
    <xs:include schemaLocation="ControlAreaType.xsd"/>
```

When I place both of these classes (Person and Company) into my project and compile. I get "ambiguous references" The classes are okay because they are partial, but the properties both inside the nested classes and outside are what is causing the issues. I have tried to place them in their own namespace but I get errors stating that you cannot put properties outside of classes within a namespace. Each class is about 5000 lines of code (no joke).

The solution that I have come up with is to place 1 of the classes (Person) into it's own project, and the other class into it's own project (Company) within the same solution. I have referenced the "PERSON" project within the "COMPANY" project where most of the code resides. I think it's kinda clunky, but it seems to compile and I've written code off of it.

Do any of you have a better solution? I cannot alter the classes since they are auto generated by the .NET XSD command.

Here is a link to the code. DL it and compile it, you'll see the error.

[TestCode](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/haewvr87g5gkxdd/AACngrAl3xDhRgviROsyY4Xwa?dl=0)

Comment: Can you show a (very small) example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you saying that Company and Person both reference each other within the XML?  Can you pare down the XML and generated classes to something that is reproducible?

Comment: I updated the orig question with a LINK to my test code

Comment: Here is the answer that worked for me!


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859319/tool-that-can-combine-many-xsd-files-into-one