# Merge (flatten) multiple XSDs into one automatically

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a more XSD files which contain the description of the message structure. 
Our application can use only one XSD so at the moment I need to merge the XSDs into one XSD manually. Take care with the namespaces and so one.

Do you have any idea how can I make it automatically without copy paste?

I have tried to generate classes from the XSDs and generate again a single XSD but that was not worked.

Answer (score 2):

The function you're describing goes by the name of *flattening* and is available in commercial XML/XSD editors such as [XMLSpy](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html), [oXygen XML Editor](https://www.oxygenxml.com/), and [QTAssistant](http://www.paschidev.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Be careful what you want. In my case I had a schema which was importing two other schema files. As all of them were using different namespaces, so they could not be "flatten" by XMLSpy. I guess this function is meant for something else then. Made the tool useless for me and I merged them manually again by copy&paste the import part into the base file.

Comment: Some XSDs cannot be flattened at all as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000894