# xslt being aware of xs:import in xsd

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have several xsd's that I do not own, that need to be converted to an in-house xml standard to work within our application.

There is an xslt script that does this for us through an ant task, but now we've come to a roadblock:
when the xsd contains an `xs:import` statement, the xslt will not be able to find the fields defined in the referenced xsd.

example xsd's:
main.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema>
    <xs:import namespace="urn:company:ns.common" schemaLocation="common.xsd"/> 
    <xs:complexType name="User">
        <xs:element ref="common:Address">
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

common.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:company:ns.common">
   <xs:complexType name="Address">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="HouseNumber" type="xs:number"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

while I can't show the current xslt since it would be akin to divulging some company information, the expected output should be something like this:

```
<User>
  <Address>
    <Street></Street>
    <HouseNumber></HouseNumber>
  </Address>
</User>
```

at this time, the xslt ignores what it can't find when it is inside the imported xsd.

wrong result:

```
<User></User>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without making one or more simplifying assumptions, you have a complex subproject on your hands, not a SO Q/A.  I'll suggest a key simplifying assumption:

- The separate XSDs' use of namespaces is organizational only and is not actually needed to disambiguate local names.

If you can make this simplifying assumption, then consider adjusting the `xsd:imports` basically to be `xsd:includes` and then using XSD [*flattening*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40508874/290085) via

1. the tool available in many commercial XML/XSD editors, or
2. W. Paul Kiel's [XML SchemaLightener](https://github.com/pkielgithub/SchemaLightener), which has a flatten function, as a tool or as a starting point as it's written in XSLT

Your XSLT could then take the single, flattened XSD as input rather than the collection of separate XSDs.

### See also

- [Merge (flatten) multiple XSDs into one automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40504970/290085)
- [Denormalize XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25605281/290085)
- [What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357943/290085)

Comment: thank you very much. I'll have a look at the provided resources. an upvote you have, an answer might follow in a few days :D